# Is it possible to separate a 2 segment control in XCode 6.0.1?

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode6

I'm developing a simple app in iOS 7 and I want to know if it's possible to separate a UISegmentedControl into 2 segments?

I like to put one segment on the left side and one on the right side of the screen.

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: the official API has no support such feature for the `UISegmentedControl`. you'd need to find some other way to isolate those segments visually (e.g. having two independent buttons looks an obvious choice for doing such job).

Answer (score 0):

no thats not per se possible with a UISegmentedControl.

you have to find another way.

One way could be to use custom UIButtons with images